# jQuery, getting position of elements around a circle

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on getting divs to rotate around a circle. I've been working on a JSFiddle which I found a while ago that seems to be nearly what I want :

**http://jsfiddle.net/c7b6H/**

But I just can't seem to get the desired effect that I am looking for. If you click the Go Right button you will see that the images smoothly rotate to positions to the right. Which is great, However when I click Go Left link they seem to jump to the left and start again.

How can I get the position of the div and then make them scroll to certain positions around the circle.  For example If I clicked go right, they would do what they do now, and if I clicked it again they would  go even further right instead of starting from the beginning again.

Here is the code:

```
var t, delta, finish;

window.goLight = function() {
    $('.circle').removeClass('right').attr("style", "");
    t = [-Math.PI, -Math.PI, -Math.PI],
    delta = [0.07, 0.055, 0.04],
    finish = [-0.5, -1.0, -1.5];
    moveit(0);
    moveit(1);
    moveit(2);
}

window.goLeft = function() {
    $('.circle').addClass('right').attr("style", "");
    t = [0,0,0],
    delta = [-0.07, -0.055, -0.04],
    finish = [-Math.PI+0.5, -Math.PI+1.0, -Math.PI+1.5];
    moveit(0);
    moveit(1);
   moveit(2);
}

function moveit(i) {
    var r = 300; // radius

    var newLeft = Math.floor(r - 50 + (r * Math.cos(t[i])));
    var newTop = Math.floor(r - 50 + (r * Math.sin(t[i])));

    $('div.circle'+(i+1)).animate({
       top: newTop,
       left: newLeft,
    },1, function() {
       t[i] += delta[i];
       if (delta[i] < 0) {
      if (t[i] > finish[i]) moveit(i);
    } else {
      if (t[i] < finish[i]) moveit(i);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/c7b6H/4/

Comment: @MackieeE Nope, if you click Go Right and then click it again you will see that it jumps back to the original position and starts again. I would preferably like it to record a position in degrees so I can move it to 90deg or 45 deg etc.. make sense?

Comment: I see :) Although I'm not sure which variables you need to save, although here you can hopefully see where I'm going with this: http://jsfiddle.net/c7b6H/5/ Saving the `i` value after animation to an `data` attribute, which you re-use

Comment: Ah, there you go, I was saving strings not numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/c7b6H/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A different version with jQuery

#### overview

Here is an example of what you've asked for, I rewrote the approach however as I find working in angle offsets more straight-forward and easier to modify. This version could be improved in a number of different ways but it is just to give you an idea. It works by translating a jQuery linear `width` animation, on a hidden non-live element, into `margin-left` and `margin-top` values by way of the [step](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step) function — rather than the use of a complicated easing function that has to circumnavigate everything with `Math.PI` calculations.

[image: screenshot of circles within circles]

#### fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nf7kA/

#### margins?

The reason I'm using margin for the positioning is so that `left` and `top` can be reserved to make sure the central hot-spots of the smaller circles is always at dead center of the larger circle. This can be achieved in a number of different ways however, it all depends on what you prefer i.e. use a separate wrapper layer to offset the small circles, or rely on css translations instead.

#### each circle has a measure object

By keeping each animation separate to it's own circle it should mean you can animate them all at different speeds and offsets, however you like really. Basically each circle has a `measure` object. This is just a hidden div that jQuery animates the "imaginary" width of. That animation is then translated to 2d coordinates by treating the `width` value as an angle (in degrees), converting it to radians and then using `Math.cos` and `Math.sin`.

#### extending the markup

The system reads-in the starting angle of the circle from the `data-angle` attribute, meaning that it should be very easy to add and remove circles at different offsets, even dynamically if you wish (although you would have to update the `spin.circles` array). You could also extend this idea by adding a `data-duration` attribute if you wanted to make particular circles move faster than their counterparts, or a `data-radius` attribute if you needed different sized circles.

Anyway, just an idea with a number of different ways it could be extended.

#### to be wary of

One thing to note with this version is that it works perfectly as long as you keep your `width` values, of the hidden divs, above zero. The second you start animating in negative values obviously things go a bit odd. This is the reason for the starting widths being defined as `8 x 360`. With this going forwards or backwards will work fine until you go backwards more than 8 times around the circle. If this is a real problem there are a number of solutions to this. The simplest being to increase the multiplier, other options are to find a `css` attribute that jQuery can animate correctly out-of-the-box either in positive or negative... I tried `z-index` and `line-height` but both have strange consequences.

#### javascript

```
jQuery(function($){

  /// a quick easing import
  !jQuery.easing && (jQuery.easing = {});
  !jQuery.easing.easeOutQuad && 
  (jQuery.easing.easeOutQuad = function( p ) { 
    return 1 - Math.pow( 1 - p, 2 );
  });

  /// the object the controls each individual circle
  var circleController = {
    create: function( circle ){
      var angle = parseFloat(circle.data('angle'));
      var obj = {
        angle: angle,
        element: circle,
        measure: $('<div />').css('width', 360 * 8 + angle),
        update: circleController.update,
        reposition: circleController.reposition,
      };
      obj.reposition();
      return obj;
    },
    update: function( angle ){
      this.angle = angle;
      this.reposition();
    },
    reposition: function(){
      var radians = this.angle * Math.PI / 180, radius = 600 / 2;
      this.element.css({
        marginLeft: (Math.sin( radians ) * radius - 50) + 'px',
        marginTop: (Math.cos( radians ) * radius - 50) + 'px'
      });
    }
  };

  /// the overall manager that keeps track of each circle
  var spin = {
    circles: [],
    left: function(){
      var self = this;
      $.each(this.circles, function(i, circle){
        circle.measure.stop(true, false).animate(
          { 'width': '-=45' },
          {
            easing: 'easeOutQuad',
            duration: 1000,
            step: function( now ){ circle.update( now ); }
          }
        );
      });
    },
    right: function(){
      var self = this;
      $.each(this.circles, function(i, circle){
        circle.measure.stop(true, false).animate(
          { 'width': '+=45' },
          {
            easing: 'easeOutQuad',
            duration: 1000,
            step: function( now ){ circle.update( now ); }
          }
        );
      });
    },
    prep: function( circles ){
      for ( var i=0, circle; i<circles.length; i++ ) {
        this.circles.push(circleController.create($(circles[i])));
      }
    }
  };

  $('#goL').click(function(){ spin.left() });
  $('#goR').click(function(){ spin.right() });

  spin.prep($('.circle'));

});
```

#### css

```
.maincircle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 600px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-300px;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width:600px;
  height:600px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color:#02E3E7;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px teal;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

#### html

```
<a id="goL" href="javascript:void(0);">Go Left</a>
<a id="goR" href="javascript:void(0);">Go Right</a>

<div class="maincircle">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="circle1 circle" data-angle="0">Movies</div>
        <div class="circle2 circle" data-angle="45">Animation</div>
        <div class="circle3 circle" data-angle="90">Something?</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ***+1*** Lovely constructed answer, although one niggle, the JS Heap size when animating those circles are quite big - I suppose unavoidable when calculating float values.

Comment: @MackieeE ~ Thanks, and good point. It's most probably `jQuery.animate` itself though. I normally construct my own animation systems but the question called for jQ and made it easier to explain :) there are a number of optimisations that could be made, you could drop `jQ.animate` and replace with `requestAnimationFrame`, and even use `transform: translate3d()` for graphics card optimisations.

Comment: Hello @Pebbl. Thanks for the detailed and constructed answer. I will take time to process it, but what do you think about using `translateX` and `translateY` to animate the movement of the elements instead of margin?

Comment: Good to hear it has been useful @bytriangle, I would definitely opt for using translation these days, and pure js. Mainly because support is no longer an issue, and you gain GPU optimisations (browser depending). That said, you could likely achieve this entire effect in CSS these days. If sticking with jQuery, however, it may have improvements to its animation that would avoid the hidden element fiddling.

Answer (score -2):

```
.circle {
      position: absolute;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      font-family:"Segoe UI";
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align:center;
      vertical-align:middle;
      background-color:#30EB0B;
      top: 91%; 
      right: 42%;
   }
  .right.circle {
     top: 89% ; 
     left: 50%;
     position:absolute;
  }
  .circle1.circle.right{
       top:xxx;
       left:xxx;
   }
  .circle2.circle.right{
       top:xxx;
       left:xxx;
   }
   .circle3.circle.right{
       top:xxx;
       left:xxx;
   }

//custom use position
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you posted the CSS?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question, let alone attempted to answer it.

Comment: @MackieeE ah, I thought I was missing something :( - Is this something that you think you can help with?